# AttributeError: "'module' object has no attribute 'ARRAY'"

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a table in SQLAlchemy where the email column is an array of email addresses. However, I'm getting this error:

```
AttributeError: "'module' object has no attribute 'ARRAY'"
```

I looked up in the docs http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/type_basics.html#sqlalchemy.types.ARRAY

but I guess I didn't understand the correct implementation.

```
import datetime
from sqlalchemy import schema, types
from sqlalchemy import orm


metadata = schema.MetaData()

def now():
    return datetime.datetime.now()

page_table = schema.Table('candidate', metadata,
    schema.Column('id', types.Integer, schema.Sequence('page_seq_id', optional=True), primary_key=True),
    schema.Column('email', types.ARRAY(String), nullable=False),
    schema.Column('first', types.Unicode(255), nullable=False),
    schema.Column('last', types.Unicode(255), nullable=False),
    schema.Column('company', types.Unicode(255), nullable=False),
    schema.Column('title', types.Unicode(255), nullable=False),
    schema.Column('linkedin', types.Unicode(255), nullable=False, unique=True),
)

class Candidate(object):
    pass

orm.mapper(Candidate, page_table)
```

Can any suggest how to make this work?

Comment: What is your sqlalchemy version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you want to use this to store multiple emails for a user.  Without an `ARRAY` type, this would traditionally be handled by creating another table -- `Email` -- with a one-to-many link to the `Candidate` table.

```
email_table = schema.Table('email', metadata,
    schema.Column('id', types.Integer, schema.Sequence('email_seq_id', optional=True), primary_key=True),
    schema.Column('email', types.Unicode(255), nullable=False),
    schema.Column('candidate_id', types.Integer, ForeignKey("candidate.id"), nullable=False),
)

class Email(object):
    pass

mapper(Email, email_table)

mapper(Candidate, page_table, properties={
    'emails' : relationship(Email, backref='candidate', order_by=email_table.c.id)
})
```

Answer (score 2):

`sqlalchemy.types.ARRAY` is new in 1.1.0, a version that has not yet been released. Unless you're on a development build of SQLAlchemy, you will not have access to that type.

Comment: ahh ok thank you. Is there anything I can do in the short term?

Comment: @MorganAllen: If you're on Postgresql, [`sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.ARRAY`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/postgresql.html#sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.ARRAY) may be an appropriate substitute. If you're not on Postgresql, SQLAlchemy doesn't seem to actually have support for SQL arrays, even with `sqlalchemy.types.ARRAY`.

Comment: I'm currently using SQLLite

Comment: @MorganAllen: I don't think SQLite has arrays.

Comment: I guess the answer would be to break out the email address's into its own table and create a foreign key?

Comment: @MorganAllen: Probably.